# Javascript namespacing only works with var

Tags: javascript, variables, namespaces, scope, var

I have the following bit of code:

```
(function(){
...
var n = n || {};
...
})();
```

This does what I want, setting n equal to {} since this is the first time it's encountered and will be undefined.  Unfortunately, since this inside a function, `n` is limited in scope to the function and I can't use it in other scripts.

I wanted to just change the line to `n = n || {}`, but I got an error:  `ReferenceError: n is not defined`

Changing it to just `n = {}` worked as expected; however, this is not what I want.  I don't get why `n`'s undefinedness causes an error when I don't use `var` and works as expected (being a falsey value used to get the right side of the OR statement) when I do.  Based on my understanding of the `var` keyword, I would expect it to be both or neither.

Why does the `var` matter, what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it sounds like you're having trouble creating a global variable.

Good.

Creating global variables in JavaScript is easier than it should be.

Your problem is that `n` is not defined (duh). You can't reference a variable that's not yet defined. But you're probably thinking, "How is that different from the version using `var`???" And that's a good question.

JavaScript does something called "hoisting" of variable definitions. If you define a variable within a function, that definition gets implicitly relocated to the top of the function. So while you wrote:

```
var n = n || {};
```

What really happened was closer to:

```
var n;
n = n || {};
```

However, it's not really that simple, because if you tried to write that code, you'd wind up with `n` always being set to `{}`. But the general essence is there. The variable declaration happens before the assignment.

If you remove the `var`, it will cause a reference error because there's no declaration to hoist anymore. So one "proper" (and I use that term loosely, because it's never "proper" to create a global variable) way to do what you want is to take your `var` and place it outside your function wrapper. Like so:

```
var n = n || {};
(function () {
    //do stuff.
}());
```

Unfortunately, you can't do it like this:

```
var n; 
(function () {
    n = n || {};
}());
```

That has the same "problem" as my example above. If `n` is defined elsewhere, it will be set to `undefined` by the `var n;` and then set to `{}` in the function. By doing the whole declaration and assignment outside the function, you get what you're looking for. Which I assume (based on the title of your question) is actually namespacing and not some arbitrary global variable. That would be naughty! ;-)

**UPDATE:**

Oh, and by the way, a better way to do this might be by explicitly referencing the global object:

```
(function (exports) {
    exports.n = exports.n || {};
}(this));
```

This will probably play better with things like node.js and anything that might wrap your code (like a `$(function() { })`).

Answer (score 2):

You've encountered the difference between an undefined variable and a defined variable with an undefined value.

Referencing an undefined variable will cause an exception (`ReferenceError: n is not defined`)

Referencing a defined variable with an undefined value is fine and will cast to `false` in a condition.

To avoid this, you can reference `n` as a property of the `window` object, as a property can never be undefined, only have an undefined value.

```
(function(){
...
window.n = window.n || {};
...
})();
```

Comment: So why is the variable already defined when I use var n and not when I use n?  Is it because it's created on the Variable object, so the new property gets created before the reference?

Answer (score 1):

`n` has not been declared yet, so checking whether `n` is true-like won't work. You can check explicitly to see if `n` has been declared yet:

```
n = typeof n !== 'undefined' ? n : {};
```

But that isn't very nice to look at. To place something in the global scope, use `window.n` in place of `n` or declare `n` outside of your function:

```
var n;

(function(){
...
n = n || {};
...
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Small change would help:

```
(function() {
    var n = window.n = window.n || {};
    // Code of your module...
    n.hello = function() {
        alert('Hello');
    };
})();

n.hello();
```

​
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/5ReWm/)**

In this way you have `n`, visible globally and a local reference `n` to the same object
inside your function.

2) I'm suggesting also you to redesign it in next way.

Make each module like:

```
var MyApplication = (function(app) {

    // Code of the module here...

    app.hello = function() {
        console.log('Hello!');
    };

    return app;
})(MyApplication || {});

MyApplication.hello();
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the function do:

```
window.n = n;
```

That will place n in the global namespace allowing you to use it in other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

With strict mode you need to explicitly use the global namespace, which is typically `window`; changing the line to use `window.n` should get you what you want:

```
window.n = window.n || {};
```

Comment: This will only work in the browser, not on the serverside. Author didn't specify. Look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571210/javascript-namespacing-only-works-with-var/12571278#12571278

Comment: @Miszy, i specified that it requires the global namespace, and any author working in a non-browser environment should be aware of what that object is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `var n;` before your code and you will have global `n`. `var` matters because it makes `n` local to the function.

Answer (score 0):

`var` creates local variable while not using it pollutes global namespace. Browsers should prevent this as mostly you don't want to create a global variable.

What you can do is using `window` object:

```
window.n = window.n || {}
```

But this will work only in browser environment. If it's not the case (eg. you're using serverside JavaScript) then retrieve the global object this way:

```
var global = (function getGlobal(){
    return (function(){
        return this;
    }).call(null);
}());
```

and then:

```
global.n = global.n || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

1) in the first round of evaluation, `var n = n || {};` you're creating the variable:

```
var n = undefined;
```

2) in the second round of evaluation, you are setting the value conditionally:

```
n = undefined || {};
```

3) without the var statement, you've got a var which doesn't exist anywhere at all, being referenced

```
var myVar = non_existant_var; // error
```

If the var already exists, say, in the global scope, or any other function which the current function is nested inside, it will use whatever `n` it finds, on the way up the chain.  If none exists, it will have a fit.

So rather than intentionally poking holes in your code, trying to get the code to know which scope you're trying to access, why not access it directly?

```
(function (name) {
    window[name] = window[name] || {}; // returns undefined and not reference error
    var ns = window[name];

    ns.init = function () {};
    // .............
    /* Don't return the application to a var -- it already exists in the global scope */
}("BigLongApplicationName"));

BigLongApplicationName.init(); // === window.BigLongApplicationName.init();
```